# Fibonacci sequence subroutine returning a value one too high

Tags: algorithm, perl, math, recursion, fibonacci

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

sub fib {
    my($num) = @_;  #give $num to input array
    return(1) if ($num<=1);  #termination condition
    return($num = &fib($num-1) + &fib($num-2));  #should return sum of first "n" terms in the fibonacci sequence
}

print &fib(7)."\n";  #should output 20
```

This subroutine should be outputting a summation of the first "x" amount of terms, as specified by the argument to the sub.  However, it's one too high.  Does this have something to do with the recursion?

Thanks.

Comment: Tiny tip: Drop the '&' - it is superfluous, and has been for ages.

Comment: @asjo, you could even say it's wrong, since it means "ignore any prototype", and there's no reason to ignore any prototypes here.

Comment: @ikegami, I was trying to be nice O:-)

Comment: @asjo , appreciated.  I'm going through a perl book that's a few years old.  I was under the impression that using '&' was better for subs b/c it would allow them to be called for before they're defined.  After a bit of research, I understand this is not the case =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) starts with `f(0) = 0` and `f(1) = 1`. After that each Fibonacci number is the sum of the previous two.

Your function uses `return (1) if ($num <= 1)` which incorrectly evaluates `f(0)` as 1. If you change this to `return $num if $num <= 1` then your sequence will start correctly.

This code outputs the first eleven numbers in the series.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fib {
  my ($num) = @_;
  if ($num <= 1) {
    return $num;
  }
  else {
    return fib($num-1) + fib($num-2);
  }
}


print join ' ', map fib($_), 0 .. 10;
```

**output**

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew the termination condition was off, but I couldn't see it before.

Answer (score 8):

20 is not a Fibonacci number. The closest is 21, the ninth. The first terms of the sequence are

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21
```

Your program outputs 21, which is the correct answer here.

If you want to compute the *sum* of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers, then you will need to update your code.  Right now you're just computing the `n`th Fibonacci number.  If you want the sum of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers, you should compute F(n + 2) - 1 by using your current function as a subroutine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!

That helps a lot.  I'm just starting to play with recursive subs; I can't believe I missed that it wasn't a sum! lol...and @ikegami , I noticed that as well.

Comment: @ikegami- Whoops!  Thanks for spotting that.  Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

templatetypedef already answered the question but I want to warn you that your implementation is terrible. It will give you the right answer if you have enough time, but unless you don't care about waiting for a few centuries you should really compute the Fibonacci sequence differently. Indeed to compute `fib(n)` you call `fib` two times which means that the complexity to compute `fib(n)` is O(fib(n)). You can achieve a O(n) complexity very simply and even a O(Log(n)) complexity, just look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: I understand that using a recursive function may not be the best implementation; however, the point of the exercise was to become familiar with recursive subs rather than to go for speed.  I totally agree with you though; it's not very practical.